# annotation with parameter for aspect

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aop, aspectj

I have an aspect usable with an annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface DumpToFile {

}
```

And the join point:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class DumpToFileAspect {

  @Around("@annotation(DumpToFile)")
  public Object logExecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

    ...
    // I likte to read out a parameter from the annotation...
    Object proceed = joinPoint.proceed();

    ...

    return proceed;
  }
}
```

I can use the aspect successfully on a method with `@DumpToFile`; however, I would like to pass a parameter to the annotation and retrieve it's value inside my aspect.
Eg. `@DumpToFile(fileName="mydump")`. Can anybody show me how to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to pass the annotation interface to the interceptor method. I haven't tried myself though.

```
Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface DumpToFile {

      String fileName() default "default value";

}
```

In DumpToFileAspect -

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class DumpToFileAspect {

  @Around("@annotation(dtf)")
  public Object logExecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, DumpToFile dtf) throws Throwable {

    ...
    // I likte to read out a parameter from the annotation...

    System.out.println(dtf.fileName); // will print "fileName"

    Object proceed = joinPoint.proceed();

    ...

    return proceed;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! however, I get an error. Already IntelliJ marks @Around red with hint `Unbound pointcut parameter dtf`'. If I start the application, I get the exception `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut 
 at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression`

Comment: mm..not sure about that. Can you double check that you imported org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint right..

Comment: `import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;`

Comment: Ah, I got it. In your example, it must be `@Around("@annotation(dtf)")` - i.e. it must match the name of parameter, not the type. - If you will fix this, I will accept the answer.

Comment: I fixed the sample code for @shakhawat so as to enable the OP to accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks, @kriegaex!

Answer (score 2):

Change your `@Around` to:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class DumpToFileAspect {

  @Around("@annotation(dumpToFileAspect)")
  public Object logExecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, DumpToFile dumpToFileAspect) throws Throwable {

    ...
    // I likte to read out a parameter from the annotation...
    String fileName = dumpToFileAspect.getFileName();
    Object proceed = joinPoint.proceed();

    ...

    return proceed;
  }
}
```

Comment: same problem here as I commented in the answer of `shakhawat`

Comment: Try bounding it to your package like:  @Around("execution(* com.your.package..*.*(..)) && @annotation(DumpToFile)")

Comment: Ah, I got it. In your example, it must be `@Around("@annotation(dumpToFileAspect)")` - i.e. it must match the name of parameter, not the type. I will accept the answer of shakhawat, because it is more complete.

Comment: I also fixed the code here. Guys, please test your code before posting an answer, otherwise you are just irritating the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
 @Around("@annotation(dumpFile)")
  public Object logExecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint,DumpToFile dumpFile)
```

Inside the `@annotation` must be the `DumpToFile` parameter name.

See the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop) for details

Comment: Actually this answer is the latest, but the first one which was correct before me fixing other people's code. If I were the OP I would accept this one.